# Openlayers 3: How to avoid "make build" after each change in code during development?

Tags: makefile, openlayers-3

In the OL3 git repository that I have cloned there are different files in the /src folder that make up the final OL3-library. Using "make build" I can create the ol.js which I finally include on a website for testing purposes. But this step takes roughly about 20 seconds which is just too long. 
Is there any better way to include all the necessary files for testing?

Comment: Unclear. `Make` builds the software from source files, 20 seconds doesn't sound long to me. What's the problem ? You don't need to do that every time you run your tests, ONLY if you edit the sources files of openlayers (which I doubt you do).

Comment: Actually I do exactly that. I am trying to implement the Modify-interaction on circles, which is not implemented in the current version.

Answer (score 1):

Just follow the [OpenLayers official quickstart](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.6.0/doc/quickstart.html).

To get started, it's enough!

In fact, to lower bandwith consumption on official website, you should replace the URLs from the quickstart with CDN URLs from https://cdnjs.com/libraries/ol3

Comment: I need to modify the library itself, not just using it through its API.